# Joomla 3 Article alternative layout

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla3.1

I've created an alternative layout for one of my articles which can be applied successfully, but as has been highlighted in various forums: if you view the article using the Single Article menu type the alternative layout doesn't get applied because of an XML override.

I have a Joomla site that is setup for Sales and Support where the article info such as date, hits etc is useful but on the marketing side none of that is needed, hence an alternative layout would work well.

I want to know how to enable my alternative layout using the Single Article menu type - I've already got the layout how I want it (testing it by having it overwrite default.php) but want to set it up as marketing.php instead and only have it applied to what is needed.

Comment: I assume you have already looked at this: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core .... If it's just hits, date etc that you want to remove on specific articles then these are controlled via parameters when you go to edit your article.

Comment: I know they can be disabled but I require a different layout. Disabling all those parameters will not disable the sidebar on my template. My question still stands on how to correctly override the default for a single article menu type. Any ideas?

Comment: Make an alternate layout instead, i.e. same thing but no xml.

Comment: As my post says, that's what I've done but it doesn't get applied when you use Single Article menu type

Comment: If you want to use it in a menu type you need to make a copy with a different name e.g. yourname.php a and copy the default.xml to yourname.xml. THen apply it there.

Comment: In what folder is that?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not going to like this answer because you have already written you're alternate view. If you were rewriting it to begin with, why would you not write in a way that the side bar parameters (date, hits, ect) are within a container that is only loaded conditionally. This way you would only have one view to worry about and a lot less headaches.